# integrate plugin into froala editor

Tags: angular, froala

I'm using `angular-froala-wysiwyg` v3 package and I want to insert into editor `jquery.atwho` plugin.

```
options: any = {
    events: {
        "initialized": (froalaEditor) => {
            console.log(froalaEditor);
            console.log(froalaEditor._editor);
            console.log(froalaEditor._editor.$el);
            console.log(froalaEditor._editor.el);
            console.log(froalaEditor._element);
            (<any>$(froalaEditor._element)).atwho();
        }
    }
};
```

And in html:

```
<div [froalaEditor]="options"></div>
```

But there is error `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__(...).atwho is not a function`

Before updating to angular-froala-wysiwyg v3 I had working code for v2:

```
options: any = {
    events: {
        "froalaEditor.initialized": (e, froalaEditor) => {
            froalaEditor.$el.atwho();
        }
    }
};
```

What should I do to fix my issue?

Answer (score -2):

Try substitue of froala if you wish to - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor